rootless podman do not start after system reboot
I followed the guide of https://hub.docker.com/r/look4/nginx to install a rootless podman container with systemd on a Ubuntu 24.04.
My container is running well but when I reboot the system my container do not start automatically. In syslog I found no errors.
Perhaps the guide is not complete. I read many articles about podman rootless systemd containers but I cannot find the missing piece.
After reboot the service is inactive:
 $ systemctl --user status nginx
   nginx.service - Look4 nginx container
   Loaded: loaded (/home/nginx/.config/containers/systemd/nginx.container; generated)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Trying to enabled the service I get the message
 $ systemctl --user enable nginx
   Failed to enable unit: Unit /run/user/1001/systemd/generator/nginx.service is transient or generated.

Thanks for helping

Are you, perhaps, looking for loginctl enable-linger?

The [Install] had an error
I changed from
WantedBy=multi-user.target

to
WantedBy=default.target

and it worked
